# Graphicsmagick Unrecognized option (-annotate)

Tags: shell, graphicsmagick

I am trying to add some text in image. I am using following command:

```
convert - -pointsize 37 -font fonts/source-sans-pro-regular.ttf -fill "#FFFFFF80" -gravity SouthEast -annotate +48+48 "some text"
```

but I am getting:

> convert convert: Unrecognized option (-annotate).

Version of graphicsmagick is:

> GraphicsMagick 1.4 snapshot-20210721 Q16

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues here.

Firstly, **GraphicsMagick** commands start with `gm`, i.e.

```
gm convert ...
gm mogrify ...
gm identify ...
```

Secondly, the `gm convert` command does not have an option `-annotate`, see list of supported options [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html).

---

Maybe you meant to install **ImageMagick** which would:

- work without `gm` prefix, as you expected, and
- accept the `-annotate` option you hoped to use.

Comment: I had to install ImageMagick beside GraphicMagick. It solved the problem.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. They are entirely separate and independent. You should not need both.

Comment: Yes, I need both, this is just part of the script